# PHP ddeboer/imap $mailbox->getMessages() with UID higher than x

Tags: php, imap

I am using ddeboer/imap (https://github.com/ddeboer/imap) in PHP.

The industry standard of an IMAP client checking mail is to:

1. save the uidvalidity of a mailbox
2. save the highest UID fetched from this mailbox
3. Then, next time you fetch emails, check whether uidvalidity is unchanged and if yes, request to get all messages with a higher UID than what you saved as the highest UID you already have. (If uidvalidity changed, fetch all messages again.)

This makes sure you will not miss out on messages.

Anyway, I can't find a way how I can do a $mailbox->getMessages() with UID as search criteria.

Comment: Since we're not the developers of this library, we can't really help you with specifics about it without going through their code, which you can do yourself as well. Just wait for them to answer the github issue you posted about it 19 minutes ago. If they don't support it, either wait for them to add it, look for another library or use PHP's `imap_*` extension directly.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Finally, after several hours of search I found it in the source code.

Comment: Check out Aurinko's Unified Email API, it supports IMAP, and it is REST:
https://docs.aurinko.io/article/18-email-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after several hours of searching, I found it in the source code:

`$messages = $mailbox->getMessageSequence('13900:*');`